# Set calendar events to available/busy

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calendar

I now have Lollipop on my phone, I wish I hadn't as it seems to have messed with the way I set my phone up. I am using the calendar for mine and my children's appointments, so some events were set up as busy and some as available. During the busy events my phone would be silenced, during the available events my phone wouldn't be silenced.

I might be wrong but I seem to be unable to do this and now all the events put the phone into silence. I do not want have my phone silenced when my children are at Tae Kwondo, but I want to be able to use the calendar to keep track of their busy social lives.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I had to share the calendar with my other email to activate the busy/available option. I don't know if it is because of the way my two emails are connected or if you just have to share the calendar.

I know that the public/private option is deactivated if the calendar is fully private (which make sense). I don't know why the busy/available option would be deactivated as well.

Comment: I guess it's because the purpose of busy/available is to give indicator for those whom you share the calendar, whether you're busy or not. If it's for personal use, then you know by yourself if you will be busy or not.